# product import phpmyadmin issues

Tags: import, sql

having issues reimporting this table any ideas what im doing wrong

> Error SQL query:
>
> --
>
> ### -- Constraints for dumped tables
>
> --
>   -- Constraints for table `mg_catalog_product_entity_text`
>   -- ALTER TABLE  `mg_catalog_product_entity_text` ADD CONSTRAINT  `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (  `store_id` ) REFERENCES  `mg_core_store` (  `store_id` ) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE , ADD CONSTRAINT 
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_TEXT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY ( 
>   `attribute_id` ) REFERENCES  `mg_eav_attribute` (  `attribute_id` ) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE , ADD CONSTRAINT 
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_TEXT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY ( 
>   `entity_id` ) REFERENCES   `mg_catalog_product_entity` (  `entity_id`
>   ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`freedomd_mage2`.`#sql-482_671e4`, CONSTRAINT
>
> `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_TEXT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCA)

Comment: Disable foreign key check when you export database, you can also disable it  when you import. disable foreign key and try again.

Comment: @SHPatel You should add this as an answer.

Comment: Okay I am adding this as answer.